# Why static properties are not accessible by "->" but accessible by "::"?

Tags: php

Here's the documentation from `static` keyword PHP.net:

> A property declared as static cannot be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).

So why the following code works?

Here's their example code (*I've shorten it*):

```
<?php
class Foo
{
public static $my_static = 'foo';
}
$foo= new Foo();
print $foo::$my_static; //print 'foo'
?>
```

Why `$foo::$my_static still` works here? Thank you everybody!

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting()` turned on? Did you get any warnings or notices? The web page does note the following: `Caution:
In PHP 5, calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.`. It might be related. What PHP version are you using?

Comment: No this example is literally from PHP manual. I just shortened it a little bit. No warning or notice for sure. And i use the 5.5

Comment: Try to use $foo->my_static or make a function inside of the foo class that uses $this->my_static and you will see the warning. You cannot use it inside the instantiated class object.

Answer (score 1):

A `::` (double colon, or `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` as the PHP parser calls it) is termed the *scope resolution operator* for a reason. **It resolves the access to a static property on an object reference.**

This appears to have been impossible before PHP 7, [however an RFC was issued to address the behavior](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax#newly_added_and_generalized_syntax) and later implemented in the language. The PHP documentation can sometimes be slow to update and include new features, and therefore mislead unless you also follow [the RFC process at wiki.php.net](https://wiki.php.net/rfc).

Comment: I understand what you say,but the document said "A property declared as static cannot be accessed with an instantiated class object" and $foo hold an object. So that is my concern. Can you have a clearer explaination?

Comment: @Best_Name The documentation is wrong (not up to date). There was an RFC to achieve this: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax#newly_added_and_generalized_syntax